# How do you get the result of a Linq statement as List?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a List with multiple rows of data that is given of a SQL database table using Entity Framework. My code to make that list is like this:

```
BarForooEntities1 barforoosh = new BarForooEntities1();
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        var q = from d in barforoosh.RadifsSendCenter
            where d.Daryaft == false
            orderby d.id_rec
            select d;
        foreach (var v in q)
        {
            list.Add(v);
        }
```

My table in database image is like this:

Table Image:

[image]

In my list and in every row of it, there are columns with values. The problem is that I want to access to all of fields in each row of my list and don't know how to do that. I searched a lot to find a solution, but the only thing that I found was access to all of one row of list by it's Index.

Is there any way to reach that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is this:

```
var list = (from d in barforoosh.RadifsSendCenter
                where d.Daryaft == false
                orderby d.id_rec
                select d).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of your RadifsSendCenter entities which you can access each column value via the properties.

Depending on what you actually want to do with each entity, you could iterate each "row" with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var radifsSendCenter in list)
        {
            // do something with the entity.
            var test = radifsSendCenter.Radifkolsal;
        }
```

Comment: I think it is the same as mine and just making the list, my problem is after making that list, how can i access to all fields of specific row in my list for example i want directly access to field "Radifkolsal" value in each row.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to show how you could access each property in the list - hope this helps?